# Wix - Disable Feature If Property Value = 0

Tags: wix

I have a installer where before the feature tree is displayed a custom action is checking if a directory exists, if it does then I want to give the user the option to install a sub feature, if the directory does not exist then the sub feature will not be displayed

My custom action at the moment is setting a variable DROPDLL to either 0 if directory doesn't exist, or 1000 if it does

I'm not trying to enable/disable the sub feature via the following but having no luck so far

```
<Feature
  Id="ServiceTierFeature"
  Level="1000"
  Title="Service Tier"
  Description="Service Tier"
  ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"
  Absent="allow"
  AllowAdvertise="no">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebSite" />
    <Condition Level ="0">DROPDLL = 0  </Condition>
      <Feature
        Id="WorkQPlugin"
        Level="1"
        Title="V2 WorkQ Plugin"
        AllowAdvertise="no"
        Absent="allow">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyRegistryKeys" />
      </Feature>
</Feature>
```

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

EDIT:

Code after below suggestions

```
<Feature
 Id="WorkQPlugin"
 Title="V2 WorkQ Plugin"
 Level="0">
  <Condition Level ="1">DROPDLL = "1000"</Condition>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyRegistryKeys" />
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be overly complicated there - it looks like you need a simple feature condition as here:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation/

and it's basically just like the example:

```
<Feature Id='Documentation' Level='0'>
<ComponentRef Id='Manual' />
<Condition Level="1">FILEEXISTS</Condition>
```

and you'd use your DROPDLL=1000 in the condition instead of FILEEXISTS. The default level is zero, and that means the feature won't be installed unless the level is set to 1, which is what happens if your DROPDLL is 1000.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply, i've now put edited the code so that it is like how you mentioned above but still have no luck, i will edit my question now with the edited code @phildw